# Accessing JSON data with Django

Tags: python, django, json

**Disclaimer:** I'm completely new to parsing and accessing JSON, and I'm only starting to get the ropes of django.

**Details:**

I'm trying to access some data inside of a JSON object I obtain in a django template:

example JSON:

```
{"entry":[
{"id":"1234567","hash":"1234567",
..."name":{"givenName":"John","familyName":"Doel","formatted":"John H. Doe"},
..."currentLocation":"Los Angeles, CA",
..."emails":[{"primary":"true","value":"jdoe@example.com"}],
..."accounts":[
    ...{"domain":"facebook.com","url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/john.doe",..."shortname":"facebook"},
    ...{"domain":"twitter.com","display":"@jdoe411","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/jdoe411",..."shortname":"twitter"}],
..."urls":[{"value":"http:\/\/www.example.com","title":"example url"},]}
]}
```

Obtained with Django Template Tag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('includes/gravatar_links.html')
def gravatar_links(email, first_name):
    url = "http://www.gravatar.com/" + hashlib.md5(email.lower()).hexdigest()
    url += '.json'

    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    interm = simplejson.load(response)
    data = simplejson.dumps(interm)
    name = first_name

return {'gravatar_links': {'name': name, 'data': data}}
```

which I just call `{{ gravatar_links.name }}` and `{{ gravatar_links.data }}`, and I can see the user's name and the JSON data as described.

**Goal:**

I want to access specific keys in the JSON object, namely `"accounts"` and `"urls"`, and customize the output, (e.g.) `"Follow {{ gravatar_links.name }} on <a href="{{ gravatar_links.data.accounts.url }}">{{ gravatar_links.data.accounts.shortname }}</a> and see their work at <a href="{{ gravatar_links.data.urls.url }}">{{ gravatar_links.data.urls.title }}</a>"`

Which ideally would produce:

`"Follow John on Twitter and Facebook and see their work at example url"`

**Questions:**

1. <strike>Should I just use django/python to do this, or is this something better handled by jQuery?</strike>
2. If the `"accounts"` come as a list, how can I output it as a comma separated list?
3. Are there any security issues I should be aware of with this method?

Comment: I would probably just use python for this and save the results since it is not likely to change.  DB access is faster than json request ... thats just my 2c though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

template tag should have been:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('includes/gravatar_links.html')
def gravatar_links(email, first_name):
    url = "http://www.gravatar.com/" + hashlib.md5(email.lower()).hexdigest()
    url += '.json'

    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    interm = simplejson.load(response)
    accounts_list = interm["entry"][0]["accounts"]
    data = simplejson.dumps(interm)

    return {'gravatar_links': {'accounts': accounts_list, 'name': first_name, 'data': data}}
```

and then to access elements of the json object we can continue to use something like `accounts_list = interm["entry"][0]["accounts"]` except with `"urls"` we'd have `urls_list = interm["entry"][0]["urls"]`

for elements with more than one possible `dictionary` of `[element: {key1=>value1, ...}, {key2=>value2, ...}]` just setup a for loop in your template and iterate through the items like this:

```
and follow {{ gravatar_links.name }} on 

{% for o in gravatar_links.accounts %}
    {% if not forloop.first and not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
    {% if forloop.last %} and {% endif %}

    <a href="{{ o.url }}">{{ o.shortname }}</a>

    {% if forloop.last %}.{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

the extra `if forloop` statements will compose our output:

`and follow John on facebook and twitter.`

more than 2 urls:
`and follow John on facebook, linkedin, and twitter.`

Answer (score 0):

For your comma-separated list you use the `join` template tag from Django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/):

```
{{ accounts|join:", " }}
```

If you want to go more fancy, you can write your own template tag (not as difficult as it seems!).

Comment: thanks, but you're right I needed to write a template tag to get this working how I want